# Can't kill rails rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I have a Rails 3.2.14 app with a rake task that listens for gps coordinates.  I'm implementing a new method of collecting gps data that doesn't require a rake task to listen.  So I'm trying to kill the rake task(s) that are spun up on my production server.

I did a `ps aux | grep rake` to get a list of the rake instances I want to kill and issued a `kill "pid"` and even the ugly `kill -9 "pid"` but the rake tasks keeps respawning.  There are three instances  of the rake task that are running that I need to kill.  Is there a better way to kill these rake tasks then what I'm doing?  I've also tried doing a `killall -9 rake` but it says `rake: no process found`

Any thoughts on how to stop this task would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was able to kill the rake processes via `Capistrano` through a Capistrano task I wrote a while back.  This killed all instances, now to remove the task from my app entirely.